# How do I find multiple occurences of a string in a string and return the index of its location in a space-separated list?

Tags: python

I have a function here:

```
def get_books(msg):
    results = []

    for key, value in books.items():
        for item in value:
            if item in msg:
                last_item = item.split(" ")[-1]
                msg_split = msg.split(" ")

                if last_item in msg_split:
                    index = msg_split.index(last_item)
                    results.append((key, index))

    return results
```

And I need to find a way to be able to have this function detect multiple books of the same name.

For example, `Exodus 1:1 blah blah blah John 1:2` returns `[("exod", 0), ("john", 5)]`, but `Exodus 1:1 blah blah blah Exodus 1:2` only returns `[("exod", 0)]`.

How would I be able to modify my function so that it will pick up the multiple instances without modifying msg_split so that the indices will stay the same?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by modifying my function to find all indices of `msg_split` enumerated:

```
def get_books(msg):
    results = []

    for key, value in books.items():
        for item in value:
            if item in msg:
                last_item = item.split(" ")[-1]
                msg_split = msg.split(" ")

                indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(msg_split) if x == last_item]

                for index in indices:
                    results.append((key, index))

    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it by using re

```
import re
alldata='yse sadsa se se'
item='se'
resultedarray=[]
for matcheditem in re.finditer(item,alldata):
        indexofs=matcheditem.start()
        resultedarray.append(indexofs)
```